# How to add day on this js time script?

Tags: php, javascript

This is my js/php displaying function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.fn.cycle.defaults.speed   = 900;
        $.fn.cycle.defaults.timeout = 5000;

        $(function() 
        {
            $('#demos pre code').each(function() 
            {
                eval($(this).text());
            });

            $('#demos2 pre code').each(function() 
            {
                eval($(this).text());
            });
        });

        $(function($) {
          var pstOptions = {
            timeNotation: '12h',
            am_pm: true,
            utc: true,
            utc_offset: <%SETTING_TIMEOFFSET%>,
            fontFamily: 'Verdana, Times New Roman',
            fontSize: '11px',
            foreground: 'white',

            background: 'black'
          }
          $('.jclockPST').jclock(pstOptions);
        });
    </script>
```

and this is my full js script:

```
/*
 * jQuery jclock - Clock plugin - v 0.2.1
 * http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jclock
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2007-2008 Doug Sparling <http://www.dougsparling.com>
 * Licensed under the MIT License:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */
(function($) {

  $.fn.jclock = function(options) {
    var version = '0.2.1';

    // options
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.jclock.defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      $this.timerID = null;
      $this.running = false;

      $.fn.jclock.getServerOffset($this);

      var o = $.meta ? $.extend({}, opts, $this.data()) : opts;

      $this.timeNotation = o.timeNotation;
      $this.am_pm = o.am_pm;
      $this.utc = o.utc;
      $this.utc_offset = o.utc_offset;

      $this.css({
        fontFamily: o.fontFamily,
        fontSize: o.fontSize,
        backgroundColor: o.background,
        color: o.foreground
      });

      $.fn.jclock.startClock($this);

    });
  };

  $.fn.jclock.getServerOffset = function(el) {
    //Want to make a synchronous call to the server to get the server time.
    $.ajax({
        url: "Time.php",
        async: false,
        context: el,
        success: function(result) {
            var serverDate = new Date(+(result) * 1000); //Convert the seconds to a number, and multiple by 1000 to get milliseconds.
            var clientDate = new Date();

            $this = $(this.context[0]);

            $this.serverOffset = clientDate - serverDate; //Set the offset between server and client.
        }
    });
  };

  $.fn.jclock.startClock = function(el) {
    $.fn.jclock.stopClock(el);
    $.fn.jclock.displayTime(el);
  };

  $.fn.jclock.stopClock = function(el) {
    if(el.running) {
      clearTimeout(el.timerID);
    }
    el.running = false;
  };

  $.fn.jclock.displayTime = function(el) {
    var time = $.fn.jclock.getTime(el);
    el.html(time);
    el.timerID = setTimeout(function(){$.fn.jclock.displayTime(el)},1000);
  };

  $.fn.jclock.getTime = function(el) {  
    var now = new Date(new Date().getTime() - el.serverOffset); //Apply the server offset.
    var hours, minutes, seconds;

    if(el.utc == true) {
      if(el.utc_offset != 0) {
        now.setUTCHours(now.getUTCHours()+el.utc_offset);
      }
      hours = now.getUTCHours();
      minutes = now.getUTCMinutes();
      seconds = now.getUTCSeconds();
    } else {
      hours = now.getHours();
      minutes = now.getMinutes();
      seconds = now.getSeconds();
    }

    var am_pm_text = '';
    (hours >= 12) ? am_pm_text = " P.M." : am_pm_text = " A.M.";

    if (el.timeNotation == '12h') {
      hours = ((hours > 12) ? hours - 12 : hours);
    } else {
      hours   = ((hours <  10) ? "0" : "") + hours;
    }

    minutes = ((minutes <  10) ? "0" : "") + minutes;
    seconds = ((seconds <  10) ? "0" : "") + seconds;

    var timeNow = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if ( (el.timeNotation == '12h') && (el.am_pm == true) ) {
     timeNow += am_pm_text;
    }

    return timeNow;
  };

  // plugin defaults
  $.fn.jclock.defaults = {
    timeNotation: '24h',
    am_pm: false,
    utc: false,
    fontFamily: '',
    fontSize: '',
    foreground: '',
    background: '',
    utc_offset: 0
  };

})(jQuery);
```

How to add Date on it, so it will display Monday, Tuesday and etc ?
My current time is obtained via time.php via `echo time();`

Thanks a lot, It will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Date object's getDay() method to achieve this. getDay() method return 0 ( Sunday ) to 6 ( Saturday ).

You need to build an array first:

```
var wdays = [ 'Sunday', 'Monday',  ... , 'Saturday'] ;
```

Then get the week day name by :

```
var weekday = wdays[now.getDay()];

timeNow += weekday; //append week day to the final result
```

Comment: can you help me implement it in my current time code ? I dont want to break something and I'll really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function day() {
  var days = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];
  var now = new Date();
  return days[now.getDay()];
}
```

now you can call the day function to get date in string `var today = day() // 'Tue' or current day`

Comment: can you help me implement it in my current time code ? I dont want to break something and I'll really appreciate it.